# Count all Contact in a Account Using Aggregate query

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    List<Contact> contacts = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;

    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        if (c.AccountId != null) {
            acctIds.add(c.AccountId);
        }
    }

    List<Account> ac = new List<Account>();

    for (AggregateResult r : [SELECT AccountId AcctId, Count(id) ContactCount 
                               FROM Contact 
                               WHERE AccountId in: acctIds 
                               GROUP BY AccountId]){
        Account a = new Account();
        a.Id = (Id) r.get('AcctId');
        a.ContactCount__c = (Integer) r.get('ContactCount');
        ac.add(a);
    }

    update ac;

}
```

If I try to save, I get the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: Incorrect SObject type: Contact should be Account at line 1 column 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to create a Contact trigger on the Account section. To make this work, go to

**Setup > Customize > Contacts > Triggers**

or to

**Setup > Develop > Apex Trigger**

Then click on the **New** button, paste the code above and save.